# unable to join tables in cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp, join, has-one

I have a two tables in database `accommodations` and `locations`. The `accommodations` table structure is :

```
id name location_id        
1  A     2
```

And the `locations` table structure is similar to :

```
id name
2  PQ
```

The `AccommodationModel.php` is:

```
class AccommodationModel extends AppModel{
    var $name = 'Accommodation';
    var $hasOne = array(
        'Location' => array(
            'className' => 'Location',
        ),
    );
}
```

But when I tried to get the `accommodation` `name` and `location` `name` from `AccommodationsController`

`$accommodations = $this->Accommodation->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions,'order' => $order,'limit'=>$limit));`

It only shows the `Accommodation` array. Why so and how can I get the location `name` ?

Comment: Did you try with Containable behavior?

Comment: Did you have a line like:
$this->Accommodation->recursive=0;
If so, make it either 1 or use Containable behaviour as skywalker said. If you have more than Location relation in Accommodation model, I would strongly recommend you to use Containable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What CakePHP-Version are you Using? Since 2.x its (without "Model" in Classname)

```
class Accommodation extends AppModel {
```

Anyways, here you go:

```
var $hasOne = array('Location');
```

..is all you need for simple hasOne - association, if you follow all Cake(Naming)Conventions.

Whats the result?